# How can I get this method return this argument?

Tags: ruby

I need to have `add_student` add multiple students to the array `grade`. The method should add multiple students to the array and assign them to `grade` or the key in the hash.

```
class School
  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  def roster
    @roster ||= {}
  end

  def add_student(student, grade)
    roster[grade] = []
    roster[grade] << student
  end

  def student_grade(grade)
    return students
  end
end
```

I do not understand why `add_student` does not add multiple arguments. I get an error that it returns only one argument or `nil`.

Answer (score 3):

Vutran's answer correctly identifies the problem, but a better solution would be to use a default proc to automatically initialize any missing value in the hash.

```
class School
  attr_reader :roster

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @roster = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = [] }
  end

  def add_student(student, grade)
    roster[grade] << student
  end

  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Every time you add a student, you reinitialize your `roster[grade]` to `[]` which discards all of previous added students. To fix this, you might change:

```
 roster[grade] = []
```

to

```
 roster[grade] ||= []
```

This line of code does the following work: it initializes `roster[grade]` to `[]` if `roster[grade]` is `nil`.